# SVN connection refused (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

I'm trying to check out my repository, but it can not connect to my project archive and refuses the connection. 
When I try to checkout in Uni it works, but not at home. I tried to change the ~/.subversion/servers file but it didn't work. I've been struggling with this issue for a long time, can anyone help me ?

```
svn: E170013: Konnte nicht mit Projektarchiv bei URL »https://www.myrepository.org« verbinden

svn: E000111: Fehler beim Ausführen des Kontextes: Verbindungsaufbau abgelehnt
```

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood the host you're trying to connect to has an "internal" name and it is either different or not available outside of the school firewall.  If you have an IT help desk you might want to ask them if the server is accessible from the outside.

Comment: no it is accessible, because it works on windows but not on ubuntu

Comment: Well then I was wrong.  Do you get any errors on the Ubuntu side?

Comment: this is the error I get when svn can not connect to the url : svn: E170013
and I this is the error when svn refuses the connection : svn: E000111 
Maybe its the firewall but I granted access at port 3690, which is reserved for svn

Comment: Do you use your universities VPN on windows but not on Ubuntu?

Comment: I used it on both, but it still didn't work on Ubuntu